# How to display a Collection in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am having a problem, I have 2 classes; Events and Participation

```
public class Events 
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventMail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Participation> Participations { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Participation
{
    public int ParticipationId { set; get; }
    public virtual Events Events { get; set; }
}
```

In XAML I want to display the events with the list of its participants

When I do this

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding EventsById}" SelectionMode="None">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Height="500" Width="500">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Participations" FontSize="18" Margin="30,10" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventName}" FontSize="20" Margin="30,10" Foreground="Black" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I get for Participations something like "System.Collection. ..."
What can I do to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: You are binding a collection property to a text block. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: First off, FFS, clean up your question.  It's not hard to format things correctly.  Secondly, use an ItemsControl.  There are plenty of examples here.